# jQuery .animate() loop produces unexpected offset over time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following Javascript code (using jQuery):

```
floatUpAndDown();
function floatUpAndDown() {
    $("#bird").animate({top: '+=30px'}, 1400)
              .animate({top: '-=30px'}, 1400, 'swing', floatUpAndDown);
}
```

`#bird` is an img tag that is absolutely positioned. Simply by looking at the code above, one should think that the bird would move 30px down, then back up 30px, and then loop forever. That is in fact exactly what happens, except for this: Over time the object happens to find itself closer and closer to the top of the page. When it has reached the top, it still continues to float up and down, but the y offset stops increasing. What do you make of this strange behaviour?

Comment: Are you also using jQuery UI?

Comment: Sounds like a rounding error to me. You can fix it by adding a statement at the start of the function that automatically moves #bird to the correct starting position -- imperceptibly, one would hope.

Comment: what if you try {top: +=30} and {top: -=30}

Comment: This works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/xQZev/1/

Comment: [Mine works fine, too.](http://jsfiddle.net/qmWgQ/) @hsdev, Is any other code affecting your bird's position?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo No, not using jQuery UI.

Comment: @mblase75 I think you are correct. Resetting the top value on every iteration works perfectly! And there can be no other parts of the code affecting it, I am quite certain of that.

Comment: @hsdev Still not sure why you have the rounding error and I didn't. But I'll repost my comment as an answer so you can close the question.

Comment: @mblase75 Well, the image is 107 pixels tall (odd number) - could that make a difference? This remains wild speculation on my part, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a rounding error to me. You can fix it by adding a statement at the start of the function that automatically moves `#bird` to the correct starting position -- imperceptibly, one would hope.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Complete rewrite because most of my previous answer was incorrect.

As per mblase's suggestion, you can use jQuery's offset() function to store the original offset, and then again to reset the element either in the callback of the second animation or at the start of floatUpAndDown().

```
var bird = $("#bird");
var birdOrgOffset = bird.offset();
function floatUpAndDown() {
    bird.offset(birdOrgOffset);
    bird.animate({top: '+=30px'}, 1400)
        .animate({top: '-=30px'}, 1400, 'swing', floatUpAndDown);
}
floatUpAndDown();
```

And just a little tip for you (or anyone else). Making calls to $()—as in $("#bird")—is kind of expensive in terms of resources. If you find that you are repeatedly invoking the same selector, it's often better to call it once and then store the result in a var as I have done in the example above. So rather than reselecting `#bird` every time we restart the animation an reset the offset, we do it once and reuse the result after that. In general, you probably won't notice...but if you're using selectors in a loop then it will definitely start to add up.

Comment: Wrong. Look again -- that first example was explicitly set with `queue: false`.

Comment: Animations would be queued in the OP's case which is what he wants.

Comment: `.animate` always queued multiple calls; jQuery 1.7 only gives you the option to disable queueing.

Comment: Well I don't know what I'm thinking of then. I just remember having some strange behavior when I was first getting started with jQuery. It's been a while since I've used the animation engine in it though. Editing again to remove the misinfo. Apologies all around!